# APA citation of two articles with no author, no date, and the same title?

Tags: citations

I'm looking to cite both of the following articles:

https://www.sourcewatch.org/index.php/Institute_for_Free_Speech
https://ballotpedia.org/Institute_for_Free_Speech

For web pages like this, my understanding is the citation should look like this:

[Title]. [Web Site]. Retrieved from [URL]

Since both have the same title, how should I distinguish between the two in in-text citations? Should I list both the title and web site somehow?

Comment: Pretty sure those articles do have dates, because they’re wiki articles that you should be able to check the edit history for?

Comment: Curious: What sort of publication is it that requires formal citations yet allows wiki articles as sources?

Comment: For citing wiki content, which is likely to change over time, it's generally best to cite to a specific dated version of the page. For instance, rather than the URL you give, I'd cite to https://www.sourcewatch.org/index.php?title=Institute_for_Free_Speech&oldid=745869 and specify "22:22, 15 February 2019" in the citation. Otherwise, a later edit might change the page so that it no longer says what you cited it as saying, and then where are you?

Comment: @puppetsockreinstateMonica Wiki cites can be appropriate for illustrating how an issue is popularly discussed/represented (e.g. the two links in the OP give very different pictures of the same organisation - that difference of representations may be of interest in itself) or when definitions are changing faster than more conventional sources can keep up. See e.g. [this article](https://digitalcommons.law.yale.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1055&context=yjolt) - it's in a judicial context but a lot of it is applicable to academia.

Answer (score 1):

`("Title of the page", n.d.a)` and `("Title of the page", n.d.b)` would combine:

- naming the title in quotation marks `"Article Title"` due to the unavailability of an author; and
- the `n.d.` (no date) due to the unavailable date; and
- the letter that is added to the date because of multiple same-titles and same-dates (`a`, `b` ...).

However, your case is special as the first link is a Wiki. As Geoffrey Brent wrote in a comment, in case of a Wiki, you can click on "View history" and find a permalink to an article's current version with a date attribution. You can then link to that versioned permalink *with* the date. [Here](https://www.sourcewatch.org/index.php?title=Institute_for_Free_Speech&action=history) is an example of a version history page pertaining to your first link; the permalink to the most recent version (Feb. 2019) is this one: https://www.sourcewatch.org/index.php?title=Institute_for_Free_Speech&oldid=745869 (you can find this link by clicking on the most recent date listed in the version history page).